# Health Issues Associated with Budweiser Prohibition?

Tags: health, non-alcoholic

After treading into the world of non-alcoholic beer, and moving away from alcohol altogether I've discovered that there are distinct disadvantages from drinking beer that still has a 0.5% ABV - most non-alcoholic beers.

And so Budweiser Prohibition serves as an interesting beer as it's 100% alcohol free. All of the taste of a standard, generic beer, with zero buzz or hangover.

My question is - despite the lack of alcohol, are there any health issues associated with drinking Budweiser Prohibition, outside of the calories it provides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are full of sugar and calories regardless of the alcohol. Treat them like soft drinks if you are counting calories.

Comment: Makes sense, although I would add that soda and beer aren't completely equivalent. They both have carbs, but beer has more complex carbs meaning it's carb 'load' is lower than soda. Bud Prohibition would also lack the weight gain from alcohol, and contains vitamins.

Comment: NA beer is around 90 calories vs. 140 for a can of sugary Coke. Either way the calories add up fast if you are drinking a few at a time. Sure there is some vitamins, mostly B (~5% daily) and some C (~2% daily) but it's hardly worth it if you think there are health benefits. The biggest health benefit is not having alcohol.